# Getting only the JSON from an ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'm using this script :

```
var test = $.ajax({ url : ("/areas/list"), type : 'GET', dataType : 'json', success : function(e) {

    } });
```

I get this result in `var text` :

```
    Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Object
responseText: "{↵ "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",↵ "columns": [↵  "INSEE_COM",↵  "KML",↵  "NOM_COMM"↵ ]}"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

The problem, is in this object, i would like get only the object in response JSON. I tried with test.responseJSON, but it doesnt work...

How can i get only the JSON ?

Thanks for your help !

F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` variables value will be the value returned by the `$.ajax()` function call, not the result. `$.ajax` will not immediately return the value from the call, its asynchronous, that's why a callback (`success: function(e) {}`) is used. The `success` callback will be called when the ajax call have successfully fetched whatever it is asked to fetch.

Check what `e` is in the success callback!

```
$.ajax({url: ("/areas/list"), type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', success: function(e) {
  console.log(e); // e == result from the ajax call.
}});
```

Comment: console.log(e) content my JSON :-) But, i dont know how to get it outside this function ?

Comment: Well, its an async callback, so you don't really know WHEN you have it. Do what it is you wish to do in the callback :)

Comment: By the way. 'e' is usually used for 'event', use 'result' or 'data' instead to make it more clear what it is you are doing :)

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything with the returned data in the success callback.

This should work:

```
var test;

$.ajax({ 
  url: "/areas/list", 
  type: 'GET', 
  dataType: 'json', 
  success: function(response) {
    // Do what ever with the response here
    console.log(response);

    // or save it for later. 
    test = response;
  } 
});
```

If you decide to save the response in a variable you won't be able to access it straight away. The ajax request wont't be complete. Best to do your processing of the JSON object in the success callback.

Comment: I tried this method. I've no error, but i dont know how to get the JSON object...

Comment: @guilb your json object is the 'response' from the ajax call. Best to do your processing inside the success callback.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to fetch value synchronously, which is not a good practice. You should try the following way:

```
var test;
$.ajax({  
    url:"/areas/list",  
    type:"GET",  
    dataType:"JSONP",  
    success:function(testdata){  
    console.log(testdata);  
    test=testdata;  
    }  
});
```

Comment: I tried this method, but i got this error : `GET http://localhost:3000/areas/list?callback=jQuery11020130594129441306_1383638694289&_=1383638694290 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:8707
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js?body=1:8707
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:8137
drawMap edit_profile5:98
(anonymous function)`

Comment: @VickyGonsalves, the curly brace is incomplete :)

Comment: i'd corrected the curly brace... I used Jite solution, it works now

Answer (score 1):

**1. Are you returning JSON data?**

In your AJAX, you're sending a request to a link at `/areas/list` - how are you handling that request in the Rails controller?

For it to return JSON data, it should read something like this:

```
#app/controllers/areas_controller.rb
def list
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { return :json => "hello".to_json }
    end
end
```

Posting your controller's code will be a big help for us all

---

**2. Are you handling the JSON data correctly?**

`JSON` data is different than "normal" javascript data. It has to be parsed when it is returned from the server, using the [JSON parse functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
$.ajax({ 
     url : ("/areas/list"),
     type : 'GET',
     dataType : 'json',
     success : function(data) {
        var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
        //do what you need here with the new array
    }
});
```